# Whats Better: Check if table exists or always fire create statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Is it OK to always fire the create statements rather than checking them like

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name'
```

in SQL SERVER CE and C#.
Because irrespective of the approach, there is always a single query that will be fired. Isnt it ???

I am using trasaction for creating all tables. So, I am sure if there is one table present, then definitely all of them are created.

So if i use the same transaction, then the transaction will fail right at the very first create table statement: But is this good performance wise???

Comment: why would you create your tables in C#?

Comment: you probably need to drop your table/ Skip Create  if there is already a table with the same name while creating. So It is Not Okay

Answer (score 2):

> Check if table exists or always fire create statement

If the table already exists in database, you will get an exception.

You can check for table existence, delete and then create it, something like:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_table_name', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.my_table_name;
--and then
CREATE TABLE ....
```

Comment: Yes I can always catch the exception. And yes, the 'if' is not supported in sql server ce.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean *try* to create the table and look for an exception, then no.  Exceptions are expensive, and if they are not handled properly can terminate your program unexpectedly.

The best practice would be to check for the table's existence.

Comment: No suppose if i do catch the exeptions correctly, then???

Comment: Checking first is still a better practice.